# Why is "Python --version" command streaming the output to stderr instead of stdout?

Tags: python, centos

I have a virtual machine which runs centOs. When I am trying to redirect the stdout of "python --version" to a file, I am not seeing any data. But when I redirect the stderr to a file, I am able to see the python version.

```
[root@CM-DM-01 ~]# python --version > /tmp/out1
Python 2.6.6
[root@CM-DM-01 ~]# cat /tmp/out1
[root@CM-DM-01 ~]# python --version 2> /tmp/err1
[root@CM-DM-01 ~]# cat /tmp/err1
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: How about `2> file` or `&> file`?

Comment: I have edited the question with appropriate commands I have tried.

Comment: @Alik Thanks. It's a duplicate question.